# How to limit array length when slice element from an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

on `BufferLimit` `if` statement satisfied i slice out first element from array and pushing new element into an array, inside `if` statement code is working as expected but i see `$scope.event` length is continue increasing even we slice out first element. is it possible to maintain array length when we slice/add elements ?

Ctrl.

```
$scope.event = [];

function safelyAdd(element) {
    if (totalReceived > Bufferlimit && $scope.event.length) {
        $scope.event = $scope.event.slice(1); //delete first element in $scope.event
        totalReceived -= $scope.event[0].messageSize; //total message size minus deleted message size
    }

    $scope.event.push(element); //then push new item..

}
```

Comment: I've tried replicating your issue, but I failed. Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle that replicates your issue? Also, instead of `.slice(1)` you can use `shift()`.

Comment: sorry dont have access to those site but slice creates new array why its kept adding to `$scope.length`..is it possible to delete element from an array ?

Comment: `slice(1)` takes all elements starting from index 1 to the last index and creates a new array.
`shift()` simply deletes the first element without creating a new array.
The problem you describe where the length stays the same doesn't make any sense with code example you provided.

Comment: as you mentioned `slice(1)` is not actually removing element from an array so that is the problem array length is growing , so i think `shift()` will work in that case.

Comment: you may try splice, as `splice(0,1)` will delete first element and return the array itself, whereas `shift()` will delete the first element but return the deleted element, not an array.

Comment: i just want to delete first elment from array i am not assigning return array to any var so i think `shift()` is good unless it changes `$scope.event`

Comment: Thank you for explanation it helps to understand the concept.